# Http Server - Are Netty FileRegions reusable?

Tags: java, http, server, netty

I am currently working on an http server and some things are behaving kind of strange.
I want to generate dynamic content and also just provide static files.
Serving dynamic generated content works without problems. 
Since I want to profit from zero copy I use FileRegions to serve static files.
My channel pipline contains the following handlers (in this order):

1. HttpRequestDecoder
2. HttpResponseEncoder
3. HttpObjectAggregator
4. ApiMapper

The ApiMapper is sharable and derived from the SimpleInboundHandler.
On creation the ApiMapper creates a FileRegion from a static file.
Now everytime the "/" uri is requested this happens:

1. A DefaultHttpReponse is written to the ChannelHandlerContext.
   The DefaultHttpReponse is not reused and contains headers for
   Content-Type and Content-Length
2. The ReferenceCount of the FileRegion is increased using its retain method.
   Then writeAndFlush is called on the ChannelHandlerContext with the FileRegion as parameter.
   To the returned ChannelFuture a ChannelFutureListener is added which prints "DONE".

The first response works as expected, the browser gets the full file and displays it correctly and "DONE" gets printed.
But if the "/" uri is called again the browser doesn't show anything and just loads forever BUT "DONE" gets printed.
Then after I restarted the server I used telnet to make the calls manually. The first response is correct, but then I noticed that the second call only returns a header, but no content.
"DONE" still gets printed.

So my question: Can the same FileRegion object be used multiple times? Am I doing anything other wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not write the same FileRegion multiple times this way as the `transferred` state is updated on the `DefaultFileRegion` object. You will need to create a new `DefaultFileRegion` instance for each write here.

Also you need to ensure you send a `LastHttpContent` after your `FileRegion` as otherwise the state-machine in `HttpResponseEncoder` will not be in the correct state when you write the second `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Therefore I could reuse LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT? Would I have to increase the reference count before sending it?

Comment: May it be better to create a direct ByteBuf, store the file content in it and reuse it then creating a new DefaultFileRegion every time?
My current application is not very time critic and load heavy, but I'm curious for future projects.